# Securing wires while replacing European electric plug

Tags: wiring

I have bought a new plug to replace my old one but it has a design I did not see before, so I thought I would better ask what is the correct way of doing it.

So, I have a cord with insulation stripped from the wires. I expected to just loop these wires around the screws (how it is done in all other cases I have seen) and be done with it but the screws in my plug seem too tiny (wires stick out of it) and wires can come off after a stronger pull. Also, there are some holes on the inner part of prongs which might be used to secure the wires. Here is a pic: 
[image]

So, my question is, how should I fasten the wires so that they would securely stay in place? Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: You have to press ferrules on the wire strands first. Then stick the secured end into the hole and tighten it. Winding strands around the screws is flub in any case.

Comment: @Janka, Ah, come on, Americans love wrapping wire [around screws](https://cdn2.tmbi.com/TFH/Step-By-Step/display/FH08APR_LAMCOR_06.JPG)...

Comment: There are ring-shaped ferrules and matching pliers for those.

Answer (score 3):

Simple. You strip the wires, turn the strands a bit, stick them in the holes and screw it tight.
Ferrules are better, but not essential*.

Then clamp the **outside shroud** of the cable with the cable clamp.

Like this:
[image: european c plug]

I've actually glued the stress relief here.

***[Notice the European C plug is limited to 2.5 Amps.](http://www.iec.ch/worldplugs/typeC.htm)**

Comment: I think it should be noted that in the OP's pic, his cable clamp is installed upside-down.

Comment: @brhans Looks like he has already disassembled the other half.

Comment: Ferrules are required by the electric code in many countries. If you don't use them and the plug catches fire and burns down your house, you are held responsible. It's easy to find out afterwards.

Comment: @Janka but not in the UK, and I would guess the rest of Europe. But since we don't have 110V appliances over here, we need *safe* connectors, unlike the some of the strange ideas about safety in the US codes. With codes like that in a highly litigious society, it's hardly surprising that people in the US are dissuaded from doing simple wiring tasks themselves! We don't build wood framed houses in Europe either, so the fire risk is much reduced - it's pretty hard to set fire to a wall built of bricks or concrete blocks with a wimpy bit of electrical cable!

Answer (score 1):

Good observation, the holes are for the wires.  The screws are nothing but *set-screws* for clamping wire after it's stuck sideways into the hole.

This wire binding is not meant to carry pull forces.

Where the game is won is in the strain relief.  That is the one screw and clamp on the left side of the picture.  It appears one of its screws is missing.  It also appears to be a plastic cheapie.  Without good strain relief, you are wasting your time.

### Don't bother.  Replace the cord.

Read the size numbers off the existing appliance cord, then buy an appliance cord *of that size*. Replace the whole cord, with pre-molded end.

This assures you get a cord/plug combo that is appropriate, and gives you better strain relief than you can get from a replacement plug.

---

I trust you know you should not be unplugging by tugging on the cable, but rather by grabbing the plug proper and pulling.

Comment: Many appliances with these plugs do not have a replaceable cord using a C7 socket. You'd have to open up the appliance, if possible, to replace the cord.

Comment: @Jeroen3 yeah, that's how you replace a cord.